# JQuery Replace Input Text Based On Current Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the value when element is selected?

```
<input type="text" value="Name" />
```

If the input box is selected, as in a single mouse click I want to clear the value. If there is not typed value when this input box, I want to restore stock value, in this case "Name". However, if there is something other than "empty space" in the box, it retains that string value.

```
$('input').on('select', function() {
    if(this).val() == 'Name') {
        $(this).val('');
    };
});

$('input'.on('unselect', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val('Name');
    };
});
```

I am very aware the 'select' and 'unselect' are incorrect.

Comment: Suggestion: use `<input type="text" placeholder="Name" />` instead. This is part of the HTML5 specification and supported by (relatively) modern browsers.  Much simpler!

Comment: Cool, that was the best solution, I can't mark as correct answer to a comment though :/

Comment: Was a down vote really necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `focus` and `blur` events:

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Name') {
        $(this).val('');
    };
});

$('input'.on('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val('Name');
    };
});
```

Alternatively, use HTML `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
```